# Linux Won't Boot From Option in Windows Boot Manager

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot

I have a pre-existing option to boot from (Windows 7), and a also made a Linux option which was made from Easy BCD.

I'm able to load Linux when I click on Windows 7 (When my external HDD with it is plugged in).

I'm able to load Windows 7 when I click on Windows 7 (When my external HDD with Linux is **not** plugged in).

Basically, I need a solution so I can get the "Linux" option in the boot manager to work. I get the error: "Windows failed to start,etc.."

Windows 7 is on my internal HDD (my default OS),and Linux is on an external Hard Drive.

Comment: Your Windows Boot record is corrupt.   You will need to repair your windows installation.

Comment: It boots just fine, that's just when I try to boot Linux.

Comment: If your BIOS doesn't give you the option to do so, then it can't be done directly.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so how would I go about doing it? I used Easy BCD do make an option in the boot manager, but it doesn't work. Only works when HDD is plugged into USB2 and I click on "Windows 7" in boot manager.

Comment: You would need a tiny Linux installation that would use <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec">kexec</a> to boot the kernel on the drive connected to the USB 3.0 port. And then that brings you back to your initial problem.

Comment: It occurs to me though, that your BIOS should not be getting confused between internal storage and external when booting. See if there is a BIOS update that remedies this, and if not then talk to the motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: When updating your progress in solving your question, please use the [edit] button instead of posting a whole new question. You can also use comments to reply to other answers and let them know if the things you're trying have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Booting off a USB 3.0 port needs BIOS capabilities.
I recall having trouble doing this over an year ago because of this reason.
Here is one AnandTech thread that I located on a cursory search: [Can you boot from USB 3.0?](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2228240)

Answer (score 0):

I'll not original, just install grub2 from linux and you be able to boot any OS correctly.

Comment: Even though my Linux is on an External HDD? How do I install Grub 2?

Comment: Won't that screw up my Windows Boot Manager as well? I'm just afraid something will go wrong.

Comment: Yes, if you're using mbr with bios (not gpt with uefi) grub will remove windows bootloader (that's normally). But you still can boot windows or any other OS, including external drives. To install grub you need do: grub install /dev/XXX in Linux (from superuser) and specify your main hdd. Read more in man grub-install.